# How to wire two dual toggle 3 way switches . one ceiling light controlled by one toggle and two outside lights by door for other toggle

Tags: wiring

I have an existing switch box inside the house that has a dual toggle switch that used to operate a door light on one toggle and two garage outside lights on the other toggle. We added a mud room out the front door so wanting to use the inside switch box for a dual toggle switch and will be adding a second dual toggle switch by the outside mudroom door and then a ceiling light and two outside lights by the door. We are wanting to operate the ceiling light on one of the dual toggles and the outside door lights on the other toggle. Need a wiring diagram on how to wire.

Comment: What happened to the original door light?

Comment: You would wire black (hot) to one side of the switch and another black that goes to lights on the other side of the switch. The neutral goes to all lights without switch.

Comment: The door light is now inside the mud room.

Comment: Ruskes, i believe I would need two 3 way duel toggle switches and 14/3 cable to switches and 14/2 cables  for lights? Just not positive on how to wire everything.

Comment: I take it the existing setup has power coming in at the switch box?